# Эллипсис глагольной группы - существует ли в русском языке?

Tags: синтаксис

На Википедии (без указания источника) сказано:

> Традиционно считается, что в русском языке данный тип эллипсиса отсутствует.

Я неоднократно слышал в разговорной речи выражение "если ещё не", напр.:

> Обязательно сделай это, если ещё не [сделал это].

Разве это не является примером эллипсиса глагольной группы в русской разговорной речи?

Comment: ------ Будешь ? :>

Comment: From my personal observation, it was almost unheard of some 30 years ago (except, perhaps, for the response "я уже" [сделал это]), but it's becoming more common, though still feels informal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Традиционно считается, что в русском языке данный тип эллипсиса отсутствует.

As was alluded to in the comments, this is not the case.

> - Я буду смотреть сериал, а он не будет.

is one example of what English linguistics calls the VP ellipsis.

Russian is not that big on auxiliary verbs as English is (see what I did here?). The VP ellipsis is less common in Russian, but it is there.

> - Обязательно сделай это, если ещё не [сделал это].

VP ellipsis elides non-finite verb forms and leaves their auxiliary verbs or particles in place. In your sentence a finite form is elided.

This would rather be an example of what English linguistics calls [stripping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripping_(linguistics)).

This distinction is just not that important for the languages that do not rely on auxiliary verbs that much. Russian can elide non-finite forms too:

> Она не любит есть суши, а я люблю.

would yield the VP ellipsis in English translation:

> She does not like to eat sushi, and I like to.

, but since Russian is not using any auxiliary verbs in this phrase, this would still count as stripping.

Comment: that is (since in russian there's one very common auxiliary verb - быть - used for future tense of non-finite forms), do you consider forms like "завтра ты сделаешь это! - не буду [делать это]!" vp ellipses?

Comment: @whyer: I guess so. Again, this distinction is not that important for Russian.